# How can I install tensorflow 1.3 with python 2.7 in a virtual environment?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, anaconda

Background: My goal is to reproduce a ML model using tensorflow 1.3 with python 2.7 in a virtual environment. Note,I installed two versions of python (2.2.18 and 3.11.3) and anaconda3 on my MacBook Pro (MacOS: Ventura 13.3.1).

**Problem:** I failed to install tensorflow 1.3. The error message I got is given below:

"DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.3.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.3.0**"

How can I successfully install tensorflow 1.3 in an environment with python 2.7?

Any help would be highly appreciated?